# Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (Intent not working)

Tags: android

App crashing after using intent to open a new activity after previous activity.
Error is showing on setContentView(). Below is the code. When i click on a button in previous activity it crashes the whole application, and does not open dexter activity.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Dexter"
android:background="@drawable/dexters_laboratory">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ply"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:onClick="playing"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
    android:background="@drawable/play_btn"/>

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/YoutubePlayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/count"
    android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="515dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@drawable/counter_bound"
    android:text="0"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/counttext"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="520dp"
    android:text="Video Views"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#6bc5ef"
    android:background="@drawable/counter_bound"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>
```

Java Code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_dexter );

 youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById( R.id.YoutubePlayer );

}

public void playing(View view) {
}
```

Comment: Post your entire stack trace

Comment: Also share your code.. It seems that R.layout.activity_dexter is wrong.